# how to send a request to Google with curl

Tags: linux, curl

I work on Linux and try to use `curl` to send requests to Google and save its reply as a html file.

When I use Google to search something, such as a string "abc", I find that the link of Google is: https://www.google.lu/#q=abc

So I try like this:

```
curl https://www.google.lu/#q=abc -o res.html
```

But the `res.html` is just the main page of Google, instead of the result of searching "abc".

How to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything after the `#` is handled client side with JavaScript, which is why it doesn't work with `curl`.

You can instead use the traditional, non-AJAX interface on `https://www.google.com/search?q=abc`

It appears to block you unless you also spoof the user agent, so all in all:

```
curl \
  -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (MSIE; Windows 10)'  \
  -o res.html \
  "https://www.google.com/search?q=abc"
```